# Pylint: E1131: unsupported operand type(s) for | (unsupported-binary-operation) with python 3.12

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

Based on [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) The above code should pass the pylint checking:

```py
# test.py
def f1(a: int | str):
    print(a)
```

But the result I got is:

```bash
$ pylint test.py
************* Module test
test.py:3:10: E1131: unsupported operand type(s) for | (unsupported-binary-operation)

-----------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10
```

Import annotations won't met this problem:

```py
# test.py
from __future__ import annotations


def f1(a: int | str):
    print(a)
```

```bash
$ pylint test.py                                                                                                                                                                       TestPlatform [ hero6api/external_device][!?⇡][ v3.12.0(.venv)]

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +10.00)
```

[Environment]
python version: 3.12
pylint: 3.03

Is this an issue unsolved yet? Or there're some mistake I did. Appreciate for answering me!

Comment: Do you have a 'py-version' <3.10 set ?

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas yes, I found that there's .pylintrc file inside of my workspace. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Closed] I check my workspace and found `.pylintrc` inside. There's one line with `py-version=3.8`. Just edit this line.